# Configuration in Azure Web App is giving error for keyvault connection: Error: Could not access key vault reference metadata

Tags: azure

[image]I am facing the issue that I am not able to connect with the Keyvault. Getting below error:

```
Error: Could not access key vault reference metadata
```

Example connection string: @Microsoft.KeyVault(VaultName=;SecretName=<secret-name)

There are not many solution available on the internet, that is why I am trying it here.

Solutions about wrong connection string are already tried.

Answer (score 0):

> Error: Could not access key vault reference metadata

- Make sure you are not passing any `curly brackets, quotations` in the ***reference value*** of the setting.
- Check if the application which is trying to access the Key Vault has all the required permissions. you can check the assigned permissions in`Key Vault=>Access Policies`.
- Instead, you can also try using `secret identifier`:

```
@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://kprkeyvault.vault.azure.net/secrets/mysecret)
```

- I have created a `secret` in my `keyvault`:

[image]

- Add **Secret Identifier** as the reference value(**SecretURI**) of the setting in `App Service=>Application Settings`:

[image]

- After **saving** the above setting, I could successfully add the Key vault reference as shown below:

[image]

**References:**

[Source app settings from key vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references?tabs=azure-cli#source-app-settings-from-key-vault)